# Vue JS - Rendering Multidemensional Obj

Tags: vue-component, vuex, vue.js

I'm new to VUE, and having a hard time figuring out how to render an Object where i don't know how many levels deep it will go.

i get this object returned from a web-api

```js
var result = {  
               "1":{  
                  "id":"1",
                  "parent_id":"-1",
                  "name":"Master",
                  "level":1,
                  "children":{  
                     "2":{  
                        "id":"2",
                        "parent_id":"1",
                        "name":"Category A",
                        "level":2,
                        "children":{  
                           "5":{  
                              "id":"5",
                              "parent_id":"2",
                              "name":"Category D",
                              "level":3
                           },
                           "6":{  
                              "id":"6",
                              "parent_id":"2",
                              "name":"Category E",
                              "level":3,
                              "children":{  
                                 "10":{  
                                    "id":"10",
                                    "parent_id":"6",
                                    "name":"Category F",
                                    "level":4
                                 }
                              }
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     "3":{  
                        "id":"3",
                        "parent_id":"1",
                        "name":"Category B",
                        "level":2,
                        "children":{  
                           "4":{  
                              "id":"4",
                              "parent_id":"3",
                              "name":"Category C",
                              "level":3
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            };
```

I ignore the first level and push it in my store. Now i'm looking for a recursive way to go over all the parent's and theire children.
(this would be an example of the desired output)

```html
<ul>
  <li>Master</li>
    <ul>
      <li>Category A</li>
      <ul>
        <li>Category D</li>
        <li>Category E</li>
        <ul>
          <li>Category F</li>
        </ul>
      </ul>
      <li>Category B</li>
      <ul>
        <li>Category C</li>
      </ul>
   </ul>
</ul>
```

However i do not get further then:

```html
<ul>
  <li>Master</li>
  <ul>
    <li>Category A</li>
    <li>Category B</li>
   </ul>
</ul>
```

And offcourse i could go on like this and then i'll reach the end of my obj. but in real situation i don't know how deep it will go, that's why i want a solution that doesn't care  about that and continiu's  till there are no more children.

I saw a little something in the doc's but that code is so different from mine that i cant really understand how to apply ( https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Circular-References-Between-Components )

My init code is basically this is everything (simplified) together :

```js
store = function()  {
    var self = this;
    self.hierarchies  = [];
    self.subView = 'hierarchies';
    self.tree = [];
};

Vue.component('hierarchies', {
    template: '#hierarchies',
    props: ['store']
});

Vue.component('products', {
    template: '#products',
    props: ['store']
});

Vue.component('treeview', {
    template: '#treeview',
    props: ['store']
});

app = new Vue({
    el: '#content',
    data: function () {
        return {
            store: {},
            tree: {}
        }
    },
    created: function () {
        this.store = new store();
    }
});


// DO AXJAX REQUEST GET HIERARCHY'S
var response = // AJAX  {};
app.store.tree.push(response[1]);
```

```html
<template id="treeview">
    <div>
        <ul v-if="store.tree.length">
            <li v-for="m in store.tree">
                {{ m.name }}
                <ul v-if="m.children">
                    <li v-for="c in m.children">
                        {{ c.name }}
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <data :tree="m"></data>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>
```

All idea's suggestions are welcome :)

Best,
Bastian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is in a pretty unpractical format since you cannot loop over object keys using the `v-for` directive. So in order to consume that format, you have to transform it into an array first. I’m using a computed property for that, but a better solution for the long run might be to transform the data once in the beginning or even changing the result format of your web service (if you can).

```js
var result = {"1":{"id":"1","parent_id":"-1","name":"Master","level":1,"children":{"2":{"id":"2","parent_id":"1","name":"Category A","level":2,"children":{"5":{"id":"5","parent_id":"2","name":"Category D","level":3},"6":{"id":"6","parent_id":"2","name":"Category E","level":3,"children":{"10":{"id":"10","parent_id":"6","name":"Category F","level":4}}}}},"3":{"id":"3","parent_id":"1","name":"Category B","level":2,"children":{"4":{"id":"4","parent_id":"3","name":"Category C","level":3}}}}}};

Vue.component('tree-root', {
  props: ['items'],
  template: `
    <ul>
      <tree-item v-for="item in items" v-bind:item="item"></tree-item>
    </ul>
  `
});

Vue.component('tree-item', {
  props: ['item'],
  computed: {
    children: function () {
      return Object.keys(this.item.children).map(k => this.item.children[k]);
    }
  },
  template: `
    <li>
      {{item.name}}
      <tree-root v-if="item.children" v-bind:items="children"></tree-root>
    </li>
  `
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    rootItem: result['1']
  }
});
```

```html
<ul id="app">
  <tree-item v-bind:item="rootItem"></tree-item>
</ul>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

What I’m doing here is use two components: `tree-root` which is responsible for rendering a list of items, and `tree-item` which is responsible for rendering a single item, eventually recursively rendering another `tree-root` for the children of each item.

The computed `children` property is used to transform the children object into a list of children.

Finally, in order to render the root component, we just render the `result['1']` which is the root element  as a `tree-item`. We could also render a `tree-root` instead with the whole `result` but then we would have to convert it first into an array (just like in the computed property), so I just opted with the simpler solution here.

Comment: Thank you Poke, for the very extensive and well explained reply. Based on your sample i got it working! Awesome, this made my day :-)

Comment: @Bastian Glad I could help! Please remember to upvote helpful answers and to ultimately [accept the answer that solved your problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/141542) to mark the question as resolved.